# How to HeatDirectory 2 or more times against directories with the same files?

Tags: msbuild, wix, wix3.5

I've been using the HeatDirectory task in our WiX installer project in the BeforeBuild target to harvest the files of a web application we deploy on the clients network.  Been working great.

I now want to deploy a second set of files, which so happens to be some documentation, and it contains files that are of the same name that exist in the previous HeatDirectory output.

I get the following error:

```
LGHT0293: Multiple files with ID 'Web.Config' exist.
```

I understand why I am getting the error, I'm wondering how best to resolve it.

**Option A**:

Copy all the files into a directory and run heat on them in one massive pass.

I like this because it would be fairly easy to implement using stock MSBuild tasks.  I dislike it because it would create one massive ComponentGroup and if I ever decided to make optional features (like not install something), I can't.

**Option B**:

Iterate over the output file of the HeatDirectory task and append a suffix on all the Component ID and File Id's.  Example - web.config would become web.config_DocumenationFiles

I like this because it's clean; i.e. I can delete it later or add it to a project that's having the issue and not add it to projects that don't.  I dislike it because I'm not sure what 'process' (or MSBuild task) is capable of doing this.  I need a custom task I think.

**Other Options**: ?

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see someone has come along and upvoted this three years later.  I thought I'd come back and state that I'm still using Option B, a custom MSBuild task to resolve the issue.

I made [a comment on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22307893/16008) about the issue with more details and thought I'd move/copy my implementation over here in case it's helpful.

I had solved it by creating a custom build task to run after the HeatDirectory task to append a suffix to the Id attribute.

```
<AddSuffixToHeatDirectory File="ReportFiles.Generated.wxs" Suffix="_r" />
```

The AddSuffixToHeatDirectory task is as such

```
public class AddSuffixToHeatDirectory : Task
{
    public override bool Execute()
    {
        bool result = true;

        Log.LogMessage("Opening file '{0}'.", File);
        var document = XElement.Load(File);

        var defaultNamespace = GetDefaultNamespace(document);

        AddSuffixToAttribute(document, defaultNamespace, "Component", "Id");
        AddSuffixToAttribute(document, defaultNamespace, "File", "Id");
        AddSuffixToAttribute(document, defaultNamespace, "ComponentRef", "Id");
        AddSuffixToAttribute(document, defaultNamespace, "Directory", "Id");

        var files = (from x in document.Descendants(defaultNamespace.GetName("File")) select x).ToList();

        Log.LogMessage("Saving file '{0}'.", File);
        document.Save(File);

        return result;
    }

    private void AddSuffixToAttribute(XElement xml, XNamespace defaultNamespace, string elementName, string attributeName)
    {
        var items = (from x in xml.Descendants(defaultNamespace.GetName(elementName)) select x).ToList();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var attribute = item.Attribute(attributeName);
            attribute.Value = string.Format("{0}{1}", attribute.Value, Suffix);
        }
    }

    private XNamespace GetDefaultNamespace(XElement root)
    {
        // I pieced together this query from hanselman's post.
        //  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetNamespacesFromAnXMLDocumentWithXPathDocumentAndLINQToXML.aspx
        // 
        // Basically I'm just getting the namespace that doesn't have a localname.
        var result = root.Attributes()
                        .Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
                        .GroupBy(a => a.Name.Namespace == XNamespace.None ? String.Empty : a.Name.LocalName, a => XNamespace.Get(a.Value))
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First());
        return result[string.Empty];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// File to modify.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string File { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Suffix to append.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
}
```

Hope that helps.  I'm still using this method today and I've not done the legwork to look into a Transform or extending HeatDirectory.

Answer (score 4):

The [HeatDirectory](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/msbuild_task_reference_heatdirectory.htm) task has `Transforms` attribute that you can use to transform the result file.  You could create an xslt to add your suffix to the Component IDs.

Also, Heat is [extensible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/icumove/archive/2009/07/02/wix-heat-extension_3a00_-setting-up-a-custom-extension-project.aspx).  You may want to look into creating your own harvester that will append a suffix to the Component Ids for you.

Comment: I like this idea Aaron.  Since I asked the question, I created a custom MSBuild task to 'fix-up' the WiX fragment file and append the suffix but that requires installing the custom MSBuild task on the Build machine and any developer machine(s) that use the project.  I'll take a look into the Transforms and XSLT first.