# HeatDirectory componentid duplicated

Tags: wix, heat

In my project there is several modules. Source files for them are generated by heatdirectory.

```
 <HeatDirectory DirectoryRefId="ServerAdminService" OutputFile="Source\ServerAdminServiceSource.wxs" Transforms="Filter.xsl" Directory="..\..\Server\ServerServiceManager\bin\Debug\" PreprocessorVariable="var.ServerAdminServicePath" ComponentGroupName="ServerAdminServiceGroup" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" SuppressCom="true" SuppressFragments="true" SuppressRegistry="true" SuppressRootDirectory="true" AutoGenerateGuids="true" GenerateGuidsNow="false">
</HeatDirectory>
<HeatDirectory DirectoryRefId="ServerAdminService" OutputFile="Source\ServerAdminClientSource.wxs" Transforms="Filter.xsl" Directory="..\Setup\C24.ServerAdmin.UI\bin\Debug\" PreprocessorVariable="var.ServerAdminClientPath" ComponentGroupName="ServerAdminClientGroup" ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)" SuppressCom="true" SuppressFragments="true" SuppressRegistry="true" SuppressRootDirectory="true" AutoGenerateGuids="true" GenerateGuidsNow="false">
</HeatDirectory>
```

It works fine. I need to install them in one directory. But they use several libraries, which are present in both modules, and after generating source files consist of the components with duplicate IDs. Actually I don't know what to do. Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the [exact same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948618/how-to-heatdirectory-2-or-more-times-against-directories-with-the-same-files).

I had solved it by creating a custom build task to run after the `HeatDirectory` task to append a suffix to the Id attribute.

```
<AddSuffixToHeatDirectory File="ReportFiles.Generated.wxs" Suffix="_r" />
```

The `AddSuffixToHeatDirectory` task is as such:

```
public class AddSuffixToHeatDirectory : Task
{
    public override bool Execute()
    {
        bool result = true;

        Log.LogMessage("Opening file '{0}'.", File);
        var document = XElement.Load(File);

        var defaultNamespace = GetDefaultNamespace(document);

        AddSuffixToAttribute(document, defaultNamespace, "Component", "Id");
        AddSuffixToAttribute(document, defaultNamespace, "File", "Id");
        AddSuffixToAttribute(document, defaultNamespace, "ComponentRef", "Id");
        AddSuffixToAttribute(document, defaultNamespace, "Directory", "Id");

        var files = (from x in document.Descendants(defaultNamespace.GetName("File")) select x).ToList();

        Log.LogMessage("Saving file '{0}'.", File);
        document.Save(File);

        return result;
    }

    private void AddSuffixToAttribute(XElement xml, XNamespace defaultNamespace, string elementName, string attributeName)
    {
        var items = (from x in xml.Descendants(defaultNamespace.GetName(elementName)) select x).ToList();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var attribute = item.Attribute(attributeName);
            attribute.Value = string.Format("{0}{1}", attribute.Value, Suffix);
        }
    }

    private XNamespace GetDefaultNamespace(XElement root)
    {
        // I pieced together this query from hanselman's post.
        //  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GetNamespacesFromAnXMLDocumentWithXPathDocumentAndLINQToXML.aspx
        // 
        // Basically I'm just getting the namespace that doesn't have a localname.
        var result = root.Attributes()
                        .Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration)
                        .GroupBy(a => a.Name.Namespace == XNamespace.None ? String.Empty : a.Name.LocalName, a => XNamespace.Get(a.Value))
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First());
        return result[string.Empty];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// File to modify.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string File { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Suffix to append.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
}
```

Hope that helps.

I'm still using this method today and I've not done the legwork to look into a `Transform` or extending `HeatDirectory` instead.

Comment: +1 for code. Thanks for that. I too really find this much easier than creating xslt transforms, which is difficult to code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Is there any guide where to locate this file to be able to make use of it?